# Is it possible to move the last character of a column to the first character of another column in excel or using python code?

Tags: python, excel, string, parsing, trim

Good afternoon , I was wondering if it was possible to move the last character of Column A to the first character of column B using excel or maybe even python. I know how to remove the last character in excel but i dont know how to go about adding it to another column?

Ex.

```
Column A = ABCD 1 , Column B = 234567
```

DEsired results:

```
Column A = ABCD,  Column B = 1234567
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59635106/edit) to show us your code?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is very broad. Do you want a solution in excel? Do you want a solution in python? What have you tried so far? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Lol of course I get voted down by the experts but I got a solution now thanks. You can go ahead and hide my question now :D

Comment: @Austin It is expected that one would show what one has tried.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me or teach me to code site.  It is a site where volunteers give of their own time to help.  And as such we expect specific problems with existing code that need to be overcome.  As this reads, you want us to take our time and write code for you for free.  That is not what this site is about.  So if one of the answers work for you, great, but remember we are volunteers not employees.

Comment: @Austin - Can you kindly mark one of the Answers that worked for you? Tick the check mark left of the Answer you used.  Also, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking "good" questions.  For example, [doing a quick search](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=move%20the%20last%20character%20of%20a%20column%20to%20the%20first%20character%20of%20another%20column%20in%20excel) for almost your exact question provides a bunch of examples you could try first before asking here.

Comment: Bruce thanks for showing me how to do it, now i know how to do it and wont have to ask anyone again. Thank you Bruce

Comment: I cant mark the answer I used due to reputation Bruce smh but I tried to vote up on both

Comment: @Austin one clicks the check mark by the answer they used to mark it as correct.  The up and down ticks take 15 rep points, but marking as correct does not require rep points only that they are the user that asked the question.

Comment: My bad Bruce, I got ya. I checked it , thanks guys wont need help on this topic anymore that i know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

In Excel:

- Define column C with the following formula:
  `C1 = LEFT(A1, LEN(A1)-1)`
  Extend downwards along the entire column.
- Define column D with the following formula:
  `D1 = RIGHT(A1, 1) & B1`
  Extend this in the same way down column D.
- Copy columns C and D, use `Paste Special > Paste Values` over columns A and B.
- You can now delete the temporary columns C and D.

Comment: Thank you for replying with an answer! Seriously appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In Column C, just use the formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

and in D:

```
=RIGHT(A1,1)&B1
```

[image]

Then copy/paste Columns C and D as Values to "lock in" column C and D.

Comment: Thank you for replying with an answer! Seriously appreciate it.